# How to stop PSReadLine from changing cursor in powershell 7.1.3?

Tags: powershell, psreadline

## *The Problem:*

The problem is that when I change the cursor PowerShell 7.1.3 to the *"Vertical Bar"* but then as soon as I type something or press enter in the terminal the cursor changes back to *"Legacy Style"*.

## *Things I have tried:*

I have tried removing the module PSReadLine by using `Remove-Module PSReadLine` but when I do that it removes the syntax highlighting which I want to keep, and of course this does solve the problem of the cursor but as I said before I want to keep the syntax highlighting because it looks very nice.

I know you can pick `pwsh.exe` in vs code default terminal and then pick the *"Vertical Bar"* option in the settings for the terminal but I don't want to open vs code every single time I want to use the terminal.

Is there a way to keep both the syntax highlighting and remove the cursor problem without removing the PSReadLine module?

Comment: This appears to be [known long-time behavior of Console Host](https://github.com/microsoft/terminal/issues/4124), using the latest version of Windows Terminal should fix it

Comment: @MathiasR.Jessen What is the latest version and how do I download it?

Comment: Launch the Microsoft Store app -> search for "windows terminal" -> install

Comment: @MathiasR.Jessen Thanks! But I want to know what is the best terminal for windows? This is just a thought that popped up in my head while downloading the windows terminal.

Comment: The best terminal is the one that works best for you - I happen to like the original Windows Console Host, so that works well for me. Try a bunch and see what works :-)